# AngularJS REST Call Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, rest

In my project I have one json files, One I deployed in the Local Machine/Server and other I deployed in the another server.

Here is my code for calling the json data from angular controller -

```
function Controller($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://localhost:8080/RESTCall/test.json").
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.lists= data;
        });
}


function Controller2($scope, $http) {
    $http.get("http://<Server IP>:8080/RESTCall/test.json").
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.lists= data;
        });
}
```

Here is my index.html page, where I am using both this controller :

```
    <div ng-controller="Controller">    
        <ul ng-repeat="list in lists">
            <li>            
            {{list.testdata}}
            </li>
        </ul>     
    </div>


    <div ng-controller="Controller2">    
        <ul ng-repeat="list in lists">
            <li>            
            {{list.testdata}}
            </li>
        </ul>     
    </div>
```

While executing I am getting the data which is coming from the Local Machine/Server OR but for Controller1 I am getting following Error :

```
OPTIONS http://<SERVER IP>:8080/RESTCall/test.json net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

When I am accessing direct `http://<SERVER IP>:8080/RESTCall/test.json` I am able to get the data..

Comment: Try it on a different browser.

Comment: @Goldenowner : I tried on Chrome and Firefox, Not working in both the cases..

Comment: Have you already tried other things to fix it? For example clearing your cache data. There are many fixes for this problem on the internet.
There is nothing wrong with your code, it's a client side error.

Comment: @Goldenowner : Yes.. I tried with cleaning the cache data also...but the json file which the controller1 is calling not loading..

Comment: May I know your server side platform?

Comment: Try to use JSONP for more info check the docs [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are firing a cross-domain request (CORS). The browser will fire a pre-flight OPTIONS request first before firing the actual GET request. Therefore you will have to configure your server to response to OPTIONS request and return appropriate Access-Control-* headers.